# python regular expression: How to find string if there are multi substrings?

Tags: python

I want to find the letters between `<b>` and `</b>` for the following string using regular expression.

```
s = "start<b>A</b><b>B</b><b>C</b><b>D</b>End"
```

The desired result is `A B C D`

I tried with these codes...

```
for i in range(4):
    r = re.search(r'.<b>.</b>.' ,"", s)
    print r
```

I also tried many other methods. But they all dont work.

Please dont give me minus, I understand it is a very beginners question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `print(re.findall("<b>([A-Z])<\/b>",s))`

Comment: If you want to avoid the "minus", read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Declaring "but they all dont work" is a prime example of how not to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall` to find all occurrences of a regex that includes `<b>`, the intermediate characters, and `</b>`:

```
import re
s = "start<b>A</b><b>B</b><b>C</b><b>D</b>End"

for match in re.findall(r'<b>(.*?)</b>', s):
    print match,
```

The parentheses in the regex serve to create a *group*, telling `findall` that you are interested in the stuff between `<b>` and `</b>`.

The `.*?` part of the regular expression means match zero or more characters, preferring the smallest string that satisfies the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample regex that will match

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'<b>(.+?)</b>')
>>> p.findall("start<b>A</b><b>B</b><b>C</b><b>D</b>End")
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the re.findall function.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'<b>(.+?)</b>', s)
>>> m
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

>>> ' '.join(m)
'A B C D'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is XML you are parsing (at least it looks like), why don't use an **XML parser**, like the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the Python standard library:

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: s = "start<b>A</b><b>B</b><b>C</b><b>D</b>End"

In [3]: root = ET.fromstring("<root>%s</root>" % s)

In [4]: [b.text for b in root.findall("b")]
Out[4]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```